# What is the proper way to update hierarchical model on changing?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following dialog model:

```
var DialogModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   user: null,

   constructor: function () {
      // Initialize user model
      this.user = new BW.user.UserModel();

      Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
   },

   parse: function (attributes) {
      _.isObject(attributes) || (attributes = {});

      // update user's model data
      this.user.set(attributes.user);
      delete attributes.user;

      return attributes;
   },

   toJSON: fucntion () {
      var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);

      // serialize user's model data to JSON
      _.extend(json, user: this.model.toJSON());
   }
});
```

As you can see from the code above, I store `user` model into `DialogModel` and set data on `parse` and serialize in `toJSON`.

As some point in time I get `dialog:update` socket message with the following data:

```
{
   id: 1,
   message: 'message',
   user: {
      <JSON USER DATA>
   }
}
```

To update dialog based on this message data I do the following:

```
eventBus.on('dialog:update', function (json) {
   dialogModel.set(json);
});
```

But the problem is that `user` model don't get updated becase `parse` method does't execute.

So my question is how could I update `user` model on `set` method?

Comment: [`parse()` is not called by `set()`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L464). You should call it manually or listen to `DialogModel` itself (within `initialize`) to on `change` and update `user` then. In my opinion you should rather move this UserModel out (to a "Controller") and feed both models separately.

Comment: Why should move `UserModel ` out to a Controller? I'm building hierarchical model such as Backbone suggests http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override [model.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).  Adding something like the following to your `DialogModel` will do the trick:

```
set: function (attributes, options) {
    this.parse(attributes);
    Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

Note that I've chosen to call the `parse` method, since it nicely sets the user data and deletes it from the attributes for us (thus preventing that data from being set on `dialogModel`).

[Click here for a fiddle demonstrating this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/rq3dygy8/).